# Split Dataframe into bins/partitions based on a column in R

Tags: r, partitioning, partition, bin, binning

I have a dataframe in R for which I have a column stating the confidence of a subject from 0-100. I would like to split the dataframe into partitions such that the same confidence judgments are put into the same partitions and the size of the partitions are almost equal. However, I do not want to split the data within the same confidence judgment (i.e., if someone has used the confidence level 100 33 times, then all of these should belong to the same partition). Also, the data should only be split at an integer level, so it should not be divided at confidence of 34.4 or similar.
I would like to have bins of similar size however as some confidence judgments are used more often than others, it is clear that they have to be of unequal size. That is fine, but I would like to get the optimum partition which keeps the size of the bins as even as possible.

I have tried to use `cut_number` however this divides the data using non-integer values such that the range of the bins go from 0 - 33.3 for example. Is there any way to achieve what I described above?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.